Should I downgrade blender if my graphics card is unsupported?
I have a laptop with an AMD firepro graphics card, when I want to render with my graphics card on blender it tells me I can't because I need to have Radeon driver 21.q4 version and above, the recent driver for my card is 21.q2.
My question is if I downgrade blender to a previous version would I be able to use my graphics card to render cycles?
P.s
I'm currently using blender 4.0, still a newbie and I'm on a windows machine

Hey, this forum is more for asking questions about how to use Blender itself. Questions about hardware are better for the Blender Discord or BlenderArtists forums.

Okay thank you. I didn't know that

No worries, thanks again!

It may be  possible.... try version 2.8, and if that doesn't work, try 2.79 (be prepared to go vastly back in time ui-wise on the second one though).
